# Shorthand to call function from scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have a function as follows (pseudocode) :

```
function doSomething (input) {
  input.something(something);
  do(input, function (res) {
    input.send(res)
  }
}
```

However, I want to be able to run it from another area, and the only shared variable between the two is `$scope`, so I do something like this:

```
$scope.doSomething = function (input) {
  doSomething(input);
}
```

Now, I can call `doSomething` using `$scope`. However, creating an extra function to do it is quite messy. Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
$scope.doSomething = doSomething(input);
```

That doesn't work though. Is there a similar shorthand you can use to create a reference to a function from another, without the need for a 'useless' function?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that if you've already declared the function. But instead of using `doSomething(input)` which is actually calling the function, use it without the brackets like so

```
$scope.doSomething = doSomething;
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is assign function pointer.

```
$scope.doSomething = doSomething;
```

what you are currently doing `$scope.doSomething = doSomething(input);` is assigning function call result, rather than pointer